# Created Angular component not visible after 'ng build'

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular and recently I started working on a simple personal SPA project. It was created using the angular cli, and the folder structure is nothing special:

```
- myApp
----e2e
----node_modules
----src
--------app
------------ main app module with two .ts components and html for each of them
...
```

Everything works fine when I use `ng serve`: I can see my components on `localhost:4200` and Angular's functionality works as a charm.

However, when I run `ng build` and from inside the newly created `dist` folder I open `index.html`, I can't see my components at all.

The `index.html` file is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>RoutingDemo</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I get no errors in the console for missing files and all of the JS and CSS files are being successfully read by the index.html.

Can someone explain why am I not seeing the components?

Comment: What do you mean by "**I open index.html**"? How are you "opening" it? You mean you're opening you're browser to the URL address that you're server is hosting the client?

Comment: `ng serve` internally uses `webpack-dev-server` to locally serve up the build files. That's not the case when you manually open up `index.html`

Comment: @Narm I mean by double-clicking it and viewing it in the browser.

Comment: @SiddAjmera has right, you can also use npm package **http-server** to run this.

Comment: @TempBird, ok that is what I suspected. That is not going to work. You need a web server that will serve up the files in your `dist` directory after completing the `ng build`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to serve your page, easiest way is to do `npm i -g http-server` and the run `http-server` from command lint in your `dist` folder, then you will be able to see your page

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now all I see is the folder structure in the browser ('Index of /' window with my project files listed). I've run the `http-server` inside of my `dist` folder..

Comment: @TempBird type index.html as the end of your url something like `http://ip:port/index.html`

Comment: @TempBird, why do you want to use `http-server` in the first place? You already have AngularCLI and you can serve the files using `ng serve`. It gives you an added advantage of running the local server in watch mode.

Comment: @TempBird `ng server` is runign a local web server like `http-server` and serves your application, you mentioned you are using `ng build`, which give you the output to host it on real server, (on servers you don't have access to ng serve), so that to see your website (to make sure everything is ok) you need to serve it separately, and then copy the files to real host on server to publish it on the net

Comment: @RezaRahmati Works as a charm :) Thanks!

Comment: @TempBird Glad it helped,so all in all for development use `ng serve`, to do smoke test before publishing to host do `http-server`